# How can I verify Project.find(12).present? and not get an error if ID 12 doesn't exist?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In the controller I want to verify if the record with the id in the query `params` exists in the database, but doing something like this `Project.find(params[:id]).present?`  errors out if the id doesn't exist.

How should I verify presence instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `find_by(id: params[:id])` (Rails 4) or `find_by_id(params[:id])` (Rails < 4) which will return `nil` instead of raising ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound.

You can also use `Project.exists?(params[:id])`.

Comment: I've been using Rails for some time now and I didn't know about the `exists?` method. Cool!

Answer (score 0):

```
Project.find(params[:id]).present?
```

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Project with ID=number

Use `Project.find_by_id(params[:id]).present?` 
while `find_by_column_name returns nil`

Answer (score 0):

In my experience there are two ways.
First and preferable, as as stated before - you can use find_by_id that returns nil if no object was found.

Second - you can use method try(:present?) - but it will return either true or nil (so you'd have to use Project.find(params[:id]).try(:present>).present? - and this seems ridiculous :) )

I also didn't know about Model.exists? method :)

Comment: This is not true, `find` raises an exception so your flow will be interrupted before it even gets to `try`. `try` returns `nil` if the caller is `nil`, so it is pointless to call `try(:present?)` in any scenario since `nil` already responds to `present?`.

Comment: True, my mistake. Well, in this case the most natural way is to find_by_id or exists?